# SQL: Select Rows which does not have a corresponding userID in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables below :

### Messages

[image]

On this table, for a particular Message, if it has a type 'Q' it's a question. Else it's a conversation from 2 users.

### Conversation Table

This keeps a track of conversations and has questionuserid and answer userid

[image]

Now from the table above, I would like to get all the messages which are not of the type `Q` and
the `userid` of that message should not be the `answeruserid` for the corresponding question in conversation table. The `id` in messages table is the `questionid` in conversation table.

This is what I tried :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    chekmarc.messages AS a
WHERE
    userid NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            answeruserid
        FROM
            chekmarc.conversations AS b 
       WHERE
            a.id = b.questionid 
    )
    AND
    a.type != 'Q';
```

But `NOT IN` corresponds to multi-level referencing, so won't work here.

This is what I tried next :

```
SELECT
    m.*,
    c.*
FROM
    chekmarc.messages m
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            chekmarc.conversations c 
        WHERE
            answeruserid IS NOT NULL
            AND
            questionid IS NOT NULL
    ) c ON
        c.questionid = m.id
        AND
        m.userid = c.answeruserid
WHERE
    m.type != 'Q'
    AND
    m.userid IS NOT NULL
    AND
    m.id IS NOT NULL;
```

But I get not matching rows and desired result. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE :**

- One `id` from messages table can be multiple `questionid` from conversations table. When the user starts the conversation, a new row is inserted under conversations and refer the `questionid` ( messages id with type = 'Q' that was posted)
- For example, when I (say user A) post a question say 'help me', multiple users now can start a conversation with respect to this question. Now 'help me' is stored in messages with a type='Q' to show it was a question. When a user say user B starts a conversation with me on question 'help me', a new row is inserted under conversations showing user A `userid` (as `questionuserid`) and user B ( as `answeruserid`). From now on any messages will be stored under `messages` table (either user A and B). So if we were to get all the convos related to user B for a message, we can check under conversation if `userid` in messages table is not the `questionuserid` in conversation table
- The tables have no relation constraints

Comment: Can a `conversation` have more than 2 `messages` associated with it? If so, what should happen if there's multiple messages from different users in the same conversation? If not, what rules or constraints are in place to prevent there being more than 2 messages?

Comment: Your screenshot shows that some rows have `NULL` values in the `status` column but others are empty-strings. I suspect this database isn't normalized.

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponds to multi-level referencing" ?

Comment: The first query looks quite fine. Only, I'd rather use `NOT EXISTS` with the correlated subquery. Be aware that `NOT IN` returns no rows, if an `answeruserid` is null. I don't understand "corresponds to multi-level referencing" either. How is the query result different from what you want?

Comment: Please show sample data. Show the related result you are after and the result you are getting with your query instead. This will help us understand the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    messages AS m1
    INNER JOIN conversations AS c1 ON m1.conversationid = c1.id
WHERE
    m1.type <> 'Q'
    AND
    m1.userid <> c1.answeruserid
```

Remember that a `JOIN` (matching rows) is not the same thing as a `WHERE x IN ( SELECT y FROM z )` predicate, even though they can both cause the same results (but only in trivial queries).

Understanding how `JOIN`s work (and when to use them) is one of the hardest parts to grok about SQL. I wish SQL tutorials and guides would introduce subqueries *after* `JOIN`s, otherwise people get the wrong mental model of SQL.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, most tutorials do teach joins before subqueries. For this reason many beginners tend to join everything and then apply `DISTINCT` to get rid of all the duplicates they produced thus, when `EXISTS` or `IN` instead would be the appropriate choice. I cannot say, whether your answer solves the problem here or not, though, because I don't understand the problem yet :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner A better solution, long-term, is to kill-off SQL and have the ISO agree to standardise on some succint syntax for relational-calculus. There's just so many things wrong with SQL today and so many _gotchas_ that scare people off and cause them to run into the arms of NoSQL vendors - with predictable results :) The idea that SQL is _mathematically pure_ because of its basis in relational-algebra is a lie when you look at how many proprietary extensions are needed to use SQL in production.

Comment: Haha, I'm quite fine with it. And I haven't seen any querying language coming even close. But, yes, with some AI involved we may see a much better language really understanding what we want in the future. (Only, there are so many people not being able to properly describe what they want. So very often we try to mind-read here. For this reason I assume some future AI tool that does the same, i.e. getting in a dialog to find out what's being asked.

Comment: I need to check again, I'm getting very few rows (57/315) from this. But I can verify

Comment: just a slight correction, I changed <> answeruserid with = ( should be the answer userid)

Comment: @rohansethi But in your original post you wrote this (emphasis mine): "and the `userid` of that message **should not** be the `answeruserid` for the corresponding question in conversation table."

Comment: @Dai Really sorry! my bad.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get all the messages which are not of the type Q and the userid of that message should not be the answeruserid for the corresponding question in conversation table. The id in messages table is the questionid in conversation table.

I think you want `not exists`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM  messages 
WHERE m.type <> 'Q' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM conversations c
                  WHERE m.id = c.questionid AND
                        m.userid = c.answeruserid
                 );
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause a correlated-subquery to be evaluated which would be suboptimal compared to a `JOIN`? Or does MySQL recognize this pattern and generate an optimal plan?

Comment: I'm getting all the rows from messages from this query

Comment: @Dai . . . I don't know what you mean.  Correlated subqueries are sometimes the fastest method for expressing certain operations.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, but the correlated-subquery *could* be evaluated for every row in `m` (where `type <> 'q') which would be bad, whereas expressing the query using JOIN operators implies/signals different intent... I'll admit I'm having trouble choosing the right words to express what I mean. Nvm :)